# How to hide the data between the two tags(<hidden> .. </hidden>) in Word document

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am able to Read the input document using Apache POI and also able to find the data between the tags(What to be hidden) but the problem is i'm unable to write the data in the output file. How can i do the same to write the data and hide it in the output generated file..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import  org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.CharacterRun;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;


public class Hidden {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("D://me1.doc");
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("D://Test.doc");
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fin);
        Range range = doc.getRange();    
        WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(doc);
        String para[] = extractor.getParagraphText();    
        String output="";
        String hidden="";
        for (String p : para) {
            String[] w = p.split("[<\\>]");             
            for(int k=0 ;k<w.length;k++){
                if(w[k]!=null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(w[k])){
                    if("hidden".equalsIgnoreCase(w[k])){                            
                        k++;
                        CharacterRun  run = range.getCharacterRun(k);
                        hidden= w[k];
                        k++;                       
                        System.out.println(hidden);
                        run.setVanished(true);
                        doc.write(fout); 
                    }else{

                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        fout.close();
        fin.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar For example see my edit, it is clear where for-loops, if statements etc end when indentation is used

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I'm new to the area,I will follow your guiding

Comment: @RichardTingle: Thank you for your kind support

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Glad to help, I wish I could help with your specific problem as well but I am yet to use Apachi